# Are there any timeframe selector web controls for .NET?

Tags: .net, iphone

I would like to use a timeframe selector in a web page, that is optimized for touchscreen usage. (e.g. large buttons).
I am actualy looking for a control that mimics iPhone UI for selecting a time frame or a time interval, say from 10:30 AM to 15:00 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the iPhone UI - I dont have one - but [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/recurrence-net/) is quite a nice timeframe / recurrence library. It might help :)